# Can you detect source language of a translation?

Tags: nlp

Sometimes you read text and you have a strong feeling that it was translated from a certain language.

For example, you read Russian text, see «взять автобус» («take bus» instead of Russian «сесть в автобус» (literally «sit on bus»)), and it becomes obvious that the text was originally written in English and then translated by low-qualified translator.

Provided you have a long text, can you automatically detect if it is translation or is it originally written in this language, and can you detect the source language? Are there any ready solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the machine translation research community, the translated text that exhibits some traits from the original language is called "translationese".

There are multiple lines of research that try to spot translationese (i.e. tell apart text that has been translated, either by human or machine, from text written directly). [Here](https://aclanthology.org/search/?q=translationese) you can see academic articles related to the matter.

However, I have not been able to find research that studies the feasibility of identifying the original source language of the translation, let alone ready-made solutions.